# A user guide about how to use this page

Tags: discussion

I am new and I was wondering if there is any guide around about how to use this page (ask patents);

Bounties, accounts, tags, badges, reputation, etc, etc.., any guide?

I am sorry if I sound like looking for a shortcut but my workload does not permit me to stay here and test things. I also don't want to bother anyone with errors..

Thanks for attention ))

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

We don't have a guide, per se, but there are some great resources.

The first place I'd stop is [our tour](//patents.stackexchange.com/tour). It goes over some of the most fundamental aspects of how all the sites in the [Stack Exchange](//stackexchange.com/sites) network work.

After that, it really just depends how you learn. For me, I'd jump right onto the site and start using it--post a question or two, post some answers, suggest edits, and you'll pick it all up. None of it is too difficult.

On the other hand, or indeed if you run into any trouble, the [help center](//patents.stackexchange.com/help) is a great place to find articles about most mechanical aspects of using the site, like ["What's reputation?"](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and ["What does it mean when my answer is accepted?"](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Once you've gone through all that, the penultimate resource is right here, on [Meta](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Meta Ask Patents is for posts *about* Ask Patents (like yours here), so you can ask about features, community expectations, issues, or even suggest new ideas about how the site should work.